# m2eclipse: Unable to update index for

Tags: svn, m2eclipse, subclipse, sourceforge

I've a simple helloworld project and I wanted to install a repository

I've eclipse, m2eclipse, subclipse, m2eclipse Extras (integration with subclipse) Installed.
I've set the settings.xml file @ home/.m2/

still when I add a repository URL it just doesn't work and gives me:

> Unable to update index for jann|https://jann.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jann

Note:
My repository is

> https://jann.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/jann

What else should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the repository in settings.xml is the repository for Maven to get the libraries needed, instead of the Subversion Repository. Maybe, you can just remove the "repository" config in settings.xml, which Maven will use the default "central" repository.